# How to initialize bean properties on a GET request?

Tags: java, database, jsf

I would like the index page to show a list of products directly, say top 10 newest or something. 
How do I do this? How do I get JSF to run a method in a backingbean on a GET request and display the results?

Comment: I don't get... why do you need this redirection? Why don't you just prepare the data you want to display in your backingbean and .. display it in your view?

Comment: Hmmm...preRenderView may be the answer, unless there are better suggestions.

Comment: @Fant that's what I want to do, but if my view is in my welcome list, my app seems to go straight to the view, I need it to run the backingbean first, but think I have an idea how to do this with preRenderView in the .jsf file

Comment: @Fant - yeah, I'm being stupid. Stuck in a Struts mentality at the moment, setting the list data I can call the data stright away with a simple #{indexView.indexListXYZ} or something.  Cheers.

Comment: Just do the job in bean's (post)constructor, yes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a request/session scoped bean, make the `@PostConstruct` update the properties with the data you want to show, access the properties from the JSF.